# Send data from Android Service to Server

Tags: php, android, json, service

I am trying to to send the database record from android to server using JSON. android code works fine(no error is displayed). But no any value is displayed in server page. Below is the android and php code.

```
package com.example.income;





import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.*;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.*;;


public class Background extends IntentService
{   
 List<HashMap<String, String>> contacts = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

public Background()
{
    super("This is the simple background class");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
{
    Log.v("message","This is simple background service");
    Db db =new Db(Background.this,"simple",null,3);
    Cursor c= db.getData();

    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {


        do
        {
            String num,dater;
            num = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("phone_number"));
            dater =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date"));

            contact.put("contact", num);
            contact.put("date", dater);
            contacts.add(contact);
      }
        while (c.moveToNext());

        try {
            sendData();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    }

public void sendData() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException 
{
    Log.v("Let's C","Will it go here?");

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.56.1/android.php");


        JSONArray array= new JSONArray(contacts);

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(array.toString());
        httppost.setEntity(se);
        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


         HttpResponse response= httpclient.execute(httppost);
         HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();

    if(entity!=null)
    {
        Log.i("response",EntityUtils.toString(entity));
    }

 }
}
```

Pho code

```
$json = $_POST['HTTP_JSON'];
$data = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: What happens if you run `print_r($_POST)`? I'm not really sure where your `HTTP_JSON` key is coming from. :-)

Comment: Array()    is displayed

Comment: print_r($data) is not giving any output?

Comment: Use `file_get_contents('php://input');` let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that instead of using HttpClient and all you use google's own volley library and return your hashmap list in its getParams() overriden method. It will be super easy to do it this way. Also, you can set headers in its setHeader method.